# Creating JButtons dynamically with WindowBuilder

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, jlabel, windowbuilder

In Eclipse, I am using WindowBuilder to develop a GUI. I am trying to dynamically create and add buttons and labels to a panel, and then update the GUI when another button is pressed to display the next set of buttons/labels.

I have been trying for hours and just cannot get it to work. The code I have is generating the first 5 buttons successfully, but then when I click 'Next' (the button that should update the GUI) it doesn't work. However, I am using sysout.println and can see that the actual text values of the JLabels I am trying to change are changing, it's just not updating on the GUI. The GUI will eventually read data from a database and populate the labels/buttons according to that, but initially I am just trying to get it to work with manually created objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I created my dynamic JRadioButton:

```
            private void createJButton (int numOfBotons)
        {
            int x=20, y=300, width=40, height=50; //choose whatever you want
            JRadioButton[] jRadioButton = new JRadioButton[numOfBotons];
            for(int i=0; i<numOfBotons; i++, y-=20) 
            {
                jRadioButton[i] = new JRadioButton(""+i);
                jRadioButton[i].setBounds(x, y, width, height);
                group.add(jRadioButton[i]);
                frame.add(jRadioButton[i]);

            }

        }
```